# I can't center the text in my listview

Tags: java, android, xml

I have this xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".AllJokes" 
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <ListView
              android:id="@+id/allJokesList"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:gravity="center">
    </ListView>


              <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"

                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-code/code"
                    ads:adSize="BANNER"
                />

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see I'm trying to center the text of the `listView` by using `android:gravity="center_vertical"`, but without a success. I have also tried to do it by: `android:gravity="center"`, but it is always left alligned.

Also in the java code I'm setting a white background to the `listView` by:

```
listView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Is it messing the things up?

Why is this happening?

I know that I'm missing something really small and basic, but as a beginner, I'm not able to spot it.

**EDIT:**

Here is the code I'm using to add items to the list view:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<String>());
        adapter.clear();
        adapter.addAll(globals.getMyStringArray());

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.allJokesList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Where `globals.getMyStringArray()` is already populated with values.

Comment: post your list item xml

Comment: @Libin The above xml is the only one I'm using for the activity.

Comment: how are your adding items to list view?

Comment: Are you using android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ?

Comment: @Libin code edited. Yes I'm using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`

Comment: ok. create your custom layout item

Comment: @Libin is right. Instead of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` you should create your own layout and set the TextView centered.

Comment: see my answer. Its very simple. I would suggest you to understand how a list item layout works when set through adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this. I copied the same android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 layout, but changed android:gravity="center"

R.layout.custom_simple_list_item

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
android:gravity="center"
android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"/>
```

change the code ..

```
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_simple_list_item, new ArrayList<String>());
```

Comment: Ok probably I should dig a bit more, on how to do it, because the xml I created in the `sdk\platforms\android-19\data\res\layout` folder can't be accessed. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Good. You have to create your own layout when your requirement is different from layout in sdk, since your are not allowed to modify the sdk files in the jar. You can modify only when you build a custom android platform